# How do i define the location of a git push to WP Engine

Tags: theme-development, local-installation, git

Ive been using Gits version control system for local theme development on a Wordpress site. I decided to take advantage of WPEngine's git capabilities which has caused more frustration than not.

I am able to push, and I have my remotes set properly but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to define where the git repository goes. My goal is to push the repository into the themes directory so any changes I make locally once pushed get updated on the staging/live site. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can just use https://wppusher.com - or contact WPEngine's support.

Comment: Awesome, the wppusher plugin looks like exactly what i need! Also been back and forth with support for days.

Answer (score 0):

Wpengine expects the root of your repository to be the WordPress root. So even though you only want to keep your theme inside your git repo the repo's directory structure needs to be:

/wp-content/themes/my-theme/